# Conflicting 'on' color for a given background error in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm making a theme for my app with jetpack compose and I have this:

```
@Composable
fun MyTheme(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {

    val colors = lightColors(
        primary = CustomColors.Custom1,
        primaryVariant = CustomColors.Custom2,
        onPrimary = Color.White,
        background = Color.White,
        secondary = CustomColors.Custom2
        )
    MaterialTheme(colors = colors, content = content)

}

object CustomColors{

    val Custom1 = Color(0xEF119335)
    val Custom2= Color(0xAA892335)

}
```

The problem is that when I add `secondary = CustomColors.Custom2`, I get an error in `onPrimary = Color.White`. The error is this:

> Conflicting 'on' color for a given background error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Error description from Compose [source code](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/43cf91a7ebf35a70c52c3b2512e1f8fb63fbd151/compose/material/material-lint/src/main/java/androidx/compose/material/lint/ColorsDetector.kt#L131)

> Background colors with the same value should have the same 'on' color
>
> In the Material color system background colors have a corresponding 'on' color which is used for the content color inside a component. For example, a button colored `primary` will have `onPrimary` text. Because of this, it is important that there is only one possible `onColor` for a given color value, otherwise there is no way to know which 'on' color should be used inside a component. To fix this either use the same 'on' color for identical background colors, or use a different background color for each 'on' color.

In your case, you have both `primaryVariant` and `secondary` set to `CustomColors.Custom2`, this means corresponding background colors should be the same too.

Default `onSecondary` color is `Color.Black`, and for `onPrimary` you've specified `Color.White`, that's why the compiler in unhappy.

You can solve this problem by specifying `onSecondary = Color.White` or by choosing different colors for `primaryVariant` and `secondary`.

If after this explanation you still wanna use these exact colors, you can silent this warning with `@SuppressLint("ConflictingOnColor")`: but some system or Material elements may not look good.